# Query fails with "com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: String didn't validate."

Tags: cassandra

I have a table created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE messages (
stream int,
sequence int,
timestamp bigint,
message blob,
PRIMARY KEY (stream, sequence)
) WITH gc_grace_seconds = 0;
```

Running the following query in CQLSH works perfectly fine:

`select * from messages where stream = 1 and sequence >= 1 and sequence <= 100;`

However, when I try to run the same via Java driver I get the following exception:

```
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException: String didn't validate.
        at com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.InvalidQueryException.copy(InvalidQueryException.java:35)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.extractCauseFromExecutionException(ResultSetFuture.java:271)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.ResultSetFuture.getUninterruptibly(ResultSetFuture.java:187)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:126)
        at com.datastax.driver.core.Session.execute(Session.java:100)
```

I'm using parameterized querying API:

```
public final String FETCH_CQL = "select stream, sequence, timestamp, message "
            + "from messages where stream = ? and sequence >= ? and sequence <= ?";

session.execute(FETCH_CQL, Integer.parseInt(stream), Integer.parseInt(fromSequence), Integer.parseInt(toSequence));
```

What gives? Overall setup works, as I have another query working on a different table.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding ; to the end of your query:

```
public final String FETCH_CQL = "select stream, sequence, timestamp, message "
            + "from messages where stream = ? and sequence >= ? and sequence <= ?**;**";
```

Another option is to use prepared statements:

```
PreparedStatement FETCH_PS = session.prepare(FETCH_CQL);
BoundStatement boundStatement = FETCH_PS.bind(Integer.parseInt(stream), Integer.parseInt(fromSequence), Integer.parseInt(toSequence));
session.execute(boundStatement);
```

Comment: Try PreparedStatement, I have added sample code to my answer.

Comment: The problem has something to do with using int as part of the key and search criteria. I have changed this field to 'text' and everything works now. This is reminiscent of the old Cassandra 1.x bug where inserting with non UTF8 key failed due to Thrift limitations. I'm guessing this is closely related.

Answer (score 0):

Define `stream` and `sequence` fields as type `UUID`